# How to add p5.dom to p5.js in instance mode

Tags: javascript, requirejs, p5.js

I'm using `requirejs` to bundle my files. I've used `p5.js` for some time, but I need to add `p5.dom` now. The problem is I don't know how to do it with my `requirejs`. I couldn't find any information how to do it with bundling.

I have something like this:

```
require(['lib/p5js/lib/p5'], function (p5) {
    var myp5 = new p5(function (_sketch) {
        _sketch.setup = function() {
           ????.createButton('click me'); // I need to access p5.dom here.
       }
    });
});
```

EDIT: When I try to use it like a variable I get `undefined`.

```
require(['lib/p5js/lib/p5', 'lib/p5js/lib/addons/lib/p5.dom'], function (p5, p5Dom) {
    var myp5 = new p5(function (_sketch) {
        _sketch.setup = function() {
           p5Dom.createButton('click me'); // p5Dom is undefined.
       }
    });
});
```

I used `shim` to ensure that `p5.js` is loaded before `p5.dom` is loaded, but it didn't help:

```
shim: {
        'lib/p5js/lib/addons/p5.dom': {
            deps: ['lib/p5js/lib/p5']
        }
    },
```

Comment: Can't you just load the P5.dom library before you load P5.js?

Comment: You mean something like this? `require(['lib/p5js/lib/addons/lib/p5.dom','lib/p5js/lib/p5']`?

Comment: I don't know, what happened when you tried that?

Comment: I updated my question.

Comment: You're going to have to take a step back and do some research on the normal way to load a library that depends on another library. There shouldn't be anything very different about Processing. How would you load Bootstrap, which requires JQuery?

Comment: I understand that the order of imports is important. If I would need to do that in html I would just declare `p5.js` and after that I would declare `p5.dom`. The problem is that there is no explanation on how to import that in instance mode, so I don't know if I should use p5Dom object separatly to create buttons, etc. or to still use `_sketch` for creating buttons and all the `dom` stuff. I've tried different combinations, none of them worked, and there is no info about it.

Comment: I don't think anything should be different about instance mode. The p5.dom library doesn't have a concept of instance mode. It's a separate library that contains its own functions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution. Unfortunately I wasn't able to do it with `requirejs`, but I simply included script tags before `requirejs` and it solved the problem. So it looks like this:

```
<script src="~/lib/p5js/lib/p5.js"></script>
<script src="~/lib/p5js/lib/addons/p5.dom.js"></script>
<script src="~/lib/requirejs/require.js" data-main="/js/scripts/tetromino-client/client.js"></script>
```

I hoped to do this in `requirejs`, but I don't understand why it didn't work.